# How to use sed to replace text with special characters

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I currently have a script that generates random words to create passwords. I run this by selecting the script and letting it know how many words I want .e.g `./generate_passwords.sh 5`. This creates five strong words.

This is the bit I am having trouble with. I want to pipe this into sed which should take the spaces between those words and replace them with random special characters. Is there a way to do this?

e.g `./generate_passwords.sh 5 | sed 's/ //g'` (This removes all spaces and inserts nothing.)

This should be the desired outcome: `word#word*word!`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the following logic:

- Define a string variables `symbols` with the symbols to pick from randomly
- Loop as long as the string contains spaces
- Use `((RANDOM % ${#symbols}))` to pick a random index
- Replace a space with the symbol at the randomly picked index

Like this:

```
s=$(./generate_passwords.sh 5)
symbols='#*!'
while [[ $s == *\ * ]]; do
    ((index = RANDOM % ${#symbols}))
    s=${s/ /${symbols:index:1}}
done
echo "$s"
```

I used parameter expansion (`${s/.../...}`) instead of `sed`.
Since this is a native Bash feature,
it will be much faster than repeatedly running a `sed` process.

Answer (score 0):

*sed 's/ //g'* removes all spaces and inserts nothing, as you write :)

sed 's/ /#/g' replaces all spaces to dies (#).

So, you need

```
 | sed 's/ /\#/'  | sed 's/ /*/'  | sed 's/ /!/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there a way to make the special characters random?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand you question.